Inserting and Sizing a Table in Word Header
How do I consistently set an inserted table's column width to both edges of an document.  The code I use works, but if the document margins vary then the table is off. Any guidance is appreciated. Below is the code I use:
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
    1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
    wdAutoFitFixed
With Selection.Tables(1)
    If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
        .Style = "Table Grid"
    End If
    .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
    .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
    .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
    .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
    .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
    .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
    .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    .Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=-62.1, RulerStyle:= _
    wdAdjustNone
    .Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=597.6, RulerStyle:= _
    wdAdjustNone



First, it is necessary to determine the proportion of the table width (i.e., table width / header width), and then the position of the table can be determined.

Option Explicit
Sub InsertTableInHeader()
    Dim pageWidth As Single
    Dim leftMargin As Single
    Dim tableWidth As Single
    Dim tableLeftPosition As Single
    Const WIDTH_RATIO = 0.5  ' modify as needed
    ' Get the width of the header
    pageWidth = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.pageWidth
    ' Get the left and right margins
    leftMargin = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.leftMargin
    ' Calculate the position and width for inserting the table
    tableWidth = pageWidth * WIDTH_RATIO
    tableLeftPosition = (pageWidth - leftMargin * 2 - tableWidth) / 2
    ' Delete existing tables in the header
    Dim tblCount As Integer
    tblCount = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables.Count
    If tblCount > 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = tblCount To 1 Step -1
            ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(i).Delete
        Next i
    End If
    ' Switch to header view and insert the table
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    ' Set up the inserted table
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
            .Style = "Table Grid"
        End If
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
        .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
        ' *** For testing to show the table
        .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        ' ***
        ' .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
        ' .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
        ' .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
        ' .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
        .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
        .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
        .Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=tableLeftPosition, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
        .Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=tableWidth, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    End With
    ' Switch back to the main document view
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End Sub



Yep, that did it! Thank you very much for your time, notes, and quick response! I'll use this as learning experience going forward. Thanks again!

You can also achieve this without opening the header. Also, as you want a table without a border, instead of applying the style Table Grid you can apply Table Normal as it doesn't have any borders.
Option Explicit

Sub InsertTableInHeader()
    Dim pageWidth As Single
    Dim leftMargin As Single
    Dim tableWidth As Single
    Dim tableLeftPosition As Single
    Const WIDTH_RATIO = 0.5  ' modify as needed
    ' Get the width of the header
    pageWidth = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.pageWidth
    ' Get the left and right margins
    leftMargin = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.leftMargin
    ' Calculate the position and width for inserting the table
    tableWidth = pageWidth * WIDTH_RATIO
    tableLeftPosition = (pageWidth - leftMargin * 2 - tableWidth) / 2
    ' Delete existing tables in the header
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        Dim tblCount As Integer
        tblCount = .Tables.count
        If tblCount > 0 Then
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = tblCount To 1 Step -1
                .Tables(i).Delete
            Next i
        End If
        Dim tblNew As Table
        Set tblNew = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Duplicate, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1, _
            DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
            AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
        ' Set up the inserted table
        With tblNew
            If .Style <> "Table Normal" Then .Style = "Table Normal"
            .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
            .PreferredWidth = tableWidth
            .Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=tableLeftPosition, _
                RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
        End With
    End With
End Sub

